# The Run Code Analysis function is missing in Visual Studio 2017 when using new csproj format

Tags: code-analysis, visual-studio-2017

I want to use the Visual Studio Code analyser for my new .netstandard libray project.
But when I right click on the project there is no analyse menu item anymore.
It seems that all projects which use the new csproj formats cannot be analysed with the analyser.

Does anybody has experience with this? Or has a clue whom to ask?

**Update:**

If I add the following to the csproj file:

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>...</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

and when I then build the project with MSBuild 15 it will run the code anaysis and generates the following warning:

*MSBUILD : warning : CA0068 : Debug information could not be found for target assembly 'CodeAnalyseTest.dll'. For b
est analysis results, include the .pdb file with debug information for 'CodeAnalyseTest.dll' in the same directory a
s the target assembly.*

But the .pdb is there. When I add now a

```
<DebugType>Full</DebugType>
```

to the csproj and then rebuild it with msbuild the code analyse works well.

**Update 2**

I opened a ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1086

Comment: You'll have to ask the programmers that work on it, click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues).  Although they almost certainly will tell you "next release", it isn't done yet.